Approximating inverse of an ill-conditioned matrix
I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question or not, it might be not really a mathematical question but more a deep learning question. But the base of question is mathematics, so I ended up asking here.
I need to implement an end-to-end trainable iterative algorithm, the problem is, there is a big sparse matrix in the middle of algorithm that is needed to be inverted, back propagating through matrix inversion is not a good idea, so I need to somehow approximate matrix inverse through some iterative methods.
Ok, now let's get into the math:
I am looking for a way to approximate a big sparse matrix inverse with a high conditioning number, the largest eigenvalue is close to 1 but the smallest is also close to 0, the condition number is quite large.
I was looking at Neuman series for approximating the inverse, the problem is, however, It needs a lot of terms, more than 1000, to get a reasonable approximation of matrix inverse which is close enough to actual inverse, due to matrix high condition number.
So I want to ask other methods or techniques for approximating a matrix inverse, which is not very well-conditioned.

What else do you know about the matrix? Also see here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35971/when-is-it-easy-to-invert-a-sparse-matrix
